# how to change logon screen for domain user in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, login, domain

i am logged on as domain user to windows 7 professional and listed as administrator , i tried changing the logon screen via

1. change in registry in authentication logon
2. change in group policy for custom background

I placed the jpg in backgrounds folder in  oobe/info but still the background does not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

windows 7 background changer 
available at

http://www.julien-manici.com/windows_7_logon_background_changer/

did the job automatically without me worrying about the settingsand its free .ALthough i will like to know how to do it manually.